# How do I remove exchange from SBS 2011 and continue all other SBS functionality?

Tags: exchange-2010, windows-sbs-2011, microsoft-office-365

I recently moved my client to Office 365 from SBS 2011. All is stable now.  They wish to continue using all the other functions of SBS i.e. Remote Web Workspace, SharePoint Calendars, TS Gateway. Should I and how do I remove Exchange from the SBS server? I currently have stopped al the services related to Exchange, and moved the mail store to archive.  Will it break anything else to remove the Exchange?  Several posts on this board refer to " remove Exchange from your SBS 2011 environment" without a hint of how, and most go on to either Migration of AD or decommission the server.  I wish SBS to continue as AD server. I see the Exchange in "Add & Remove Programs" could it be that easy?  And again will it break anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't remove Exchange from SBS 2011, it's not supported, it WILL break things and there's absolutely no point in doing it.

Comment: I expected as much, but could not find a definitive answer.  Thanks for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

Stop & Disable all Exchange Service, as you will end up with problem if the uninstall is done incorrectly.

A example for SBS 2008; https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd728003(WS.10).aspx, and please take note that those steps seem to not had been wrote for SBS 2011, so is it supported ?